# What user is queueable apex class running as?

Tags: queueable-apex, asyncapexjob

I have a queueable class, that is executed correctly (and working asynchronosly calling external services)

I have an issue, that within the class, the following line:
system.UserInfo.getUserEmail()
does not return the correct email, but it returns the system admin email (mine).

Looking at the Apex jobs, I always see the admin user as the job submitter.

[image]

Is there a way to have that by the running user?

Comment: is the job enqueued from the trigger context or from a different scenario?

Comment: The enqueue is from a scheduled job/repeater. That I have initiated (did I answer my question?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user who initiates the queueable call will be the running user. This is generally true for the other asynchronous types, as well (e.g. Scheduable, Batchable). There are a few exceptions, though, such as managed package post-install handlers (will be a "package user") and Platform Event Triggers (will be the Automated User).